# piecewise potention of Matrix

Tags: matrix-equations

Is there a a name for the piecewise potention of a Matrix. Simular to the Hadamard product for multiplication?

In Matlab code this would be: A.^x

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps unsurprisingly, this is called the [Hadamard power](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22hadamard+power+of+a+matrix%22) of a matrix.